# Anatomy suffixes?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology

Here are some suffixes I want to know their meaning:

*-ium*: trapezium (carpal bone)
*-ius*: trapezius  (column muscle)
*-ous*: Talous and calcanous (tarsal bone)
*-alis*: Acromialis, Ulnaris (shoulder proccess and bone of forearm)
*-ate*: Capitate, Hamate, lunate (carpal bones)

What is the difference between *tuber* and *tubercle*?

How to know where to use these suffixes, they are randomly given or it has to do with location or something?

Comment: I cant even understand what you are asking here. Edit your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These names originate from latin <sup>[1]</sup>.

- *-ium* is the second declension of a noun in accusative (*trapezium* refers to a bone thus is a **noun**)
- *-ius* is a genitive adjective suffix (*trapezius* is the name of a muscle thus being an **adjective**)
- you have written them wrong: *talus* and *calcaneus* is correct. They are both nominative **nouns**.
- there is no *-alis* suffix; it is either *-is* or *-lis*. They are **adjective** suffixes.
- there is no *-ate* suffix. Those are **nouns**.

*Tuber* is the latin word for *tuberosity*. It is the quality or condition of a *tubercle* (adjective) <sup>[2]</sup>.

References:

1. Wikipedia, [*Latin declension*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_declension)
2. The Free Dictionary by Farlex, *[Tubercle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Tubercle+%28anatomy%29)*